# How to simulate nodeNotReady for a node in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

My ceph cluster is running on AWS with `3 masters 3 workers` configuration. When I do `kubectl get nodes` it shows me all the nodes in the `ready` state.
Is there is any way I can simulate manually to get `nodeNotReady` error for a node?.

Answer (score 2):

just stop kebelet service on one of the node that you want to see as NodeNotReady

Comment: can u please tell me how to stop the kubelet service?.

Comment: systemctl stop kubelet.service

Comment: But my cluster is running on AWS, all my nodes are hosted up there.

Comment: The idea you are suggesting will help locally and not if my cluster is running on a server like AWS.

Comment: If your cluster is running on AWS you can still ssh to the node VM and run whatever command you wish

Answer (score 1):

If you just want NodeNotReady you can delete the CNI you have installed. 
`kubectl get all -n kube-system` find the DaemonSet of your CNI and delete it or just do a reverse of installing it: `kubectl delete -f link_to_your_CNI_yaml`

You could also try to overwhelm the node with too many pods (resources). You can also share your main goal so we can adjust the answer.

About the answer from P Ekambaram you could just ssh to a node and then stop the kubelet.

To do that in kops you can just:

`ssh -A admin@Node_PublicDNS_name`

`systemctl stop kubelet`

**EDIT:**
Another way is to overload the Node which will cause: `System OOM encountered` and that will result in Node NotReady state. 
This is just one of the ways of how to achieve it:
SSH into the Node you want to get into NotReady
Install [Stress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948854/how-do-i-stress-test-cpu-and-ram-at-the-same-time)
Run stress: `stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --hdd 10 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 1024M --timeout 5m` (you can adjust the values of course) 
Wait till Node crash. 
After you stop the stress the Node should get back to healthy state automatically.

Comment: I tried some other solutions like overwhelming the node, but the easiest solution and without making additional mess would be to just ssh to a node and stop the kubelet.

Comment: My question is that If you tried running everything on AWS cluster?.

Comment: and is there's any way in which if we can simulate nodeNotReady abruptly?.

Comment: yes I tried this on kops. Stoping the kubelet will result in NodeNotReady. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I wanted to land in `nodeNotready` state somehow and try to see what all things happen to my cluster which is loaded by data atm.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and let me know what can I do to achieve that?.

Comment: it is written at the end.  find the EC2 DNS name of the node you want to get into (you can do that using aws cli or going to aws console and clicking connect to that machine to get its name)  and ssh to it using `ssh -A admin@Node_PublicDNS_name` and then run `systemctl stop kubelet` then again run kubectl get nodes and your node will be in NotReady state.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the purpose to simulate **NotReady**

1. if the purpose is to not schedule any new pods then you can use `kubectl cordon node 
   NODE_NAME` This will add the unschedulable taint to it and prevent new pods from being scheduled there.
2. If the purpose is to evict existing pod then you can use `kubectl drain NODE_NAME`

In general you can play with [taints and toleration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) to achieve your goal related to the above and you can much more with those!

Now **NotReady** status comes from the taint *node.kubernetes.io/not-ready* [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions)
Which is set by

> In version 1.13, the TaintBasedEvictions feature is promoted to beta and enabled by default, hence the taints are automatically added by the NodeController

Therefore if you want to manually set that taint `kubectl taint node NODE_NAME node.kubernetes.io/not-ready=:NoExecute` the NodeController will reset it automatically!

So to absolutely see the NotReady status [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56705674/4451944) is the best way

Lastly, if you want to remove your networking in a particular node then you can taint it like this `kubectl taint node NODE_NAME dedicated/not-ready=:NoExecute`

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like what you are trying to do is mimic a trouble condition. If that is so, you can force a node pressure condition. DiskPressure is an easy one:

- Easiest way to do this is to ssh into the node vm directly, then run 
  `fallocate -l 100GB /bigfile` 
  you want to get the disk usage up to about 93% full, that should trigger the DiskPressure condition.
- You can do the same thing through a pod, however K8s will evict that pod and try to heal the condition. The DiskPressure condition will reset a few minutes after the pod is deleted.

Adding a Node Pressure condition does not mark the node as Not Ready - it will be Ready, with a pressure condition. It will have a taint that will make it unschedulable for most new workloads until the condition is resolved.

But that might do what you are looking for.