# Custom conditions for k8s node status

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there anyway we could include custom node [conditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#condition) in k8s and mark a Node is not ready until those conditions are met. Kubectl should return Status as NotReady if custom condition is not met

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                         STATUS   ROLES        AGE   VERSION
ip-10-24-11-46.eu-west-1.compute.internal    Ready    master       23d   v1.18.3
ip-10-24-12-111.eu-west-1.compute.internal   NotReady worker       23d   v1.18.3
ip-10-24-12-197.eu-west-1.compute.internal   Ready    worker       22d   v1.18.3
```

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality.  However, what you can do is create script with will

1. check your needed conditions.
2. If conditions doesnt met - ssh to that node and shoot yourself into leg by hitting `systemctl stop kubelet` :)
3. continue check condition
4. as soon as condition met - ssh to same node and `systemctl start kubelet`

Idea with stopping kubelet has been taken from [How to simulate nodeNotReady for a node in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56684940/9929015)

But really, would be interesting to know use case...