# How to set Node status Manually

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I am working on a use case where I need [node status Not Ready](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/). I know that [node cordon](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#manual-node-administration) `kubectl cordon NODE` but this will mark node as `Ready,SchedulingDisabled`.

For example

```
kubectl cordon node_id
```

[image]

So is there a way to manually set node status **Not Ready** in AWS EKS?

[image]

Comment: what is the use case for such scenario? The nodes post NotReady status when the kubelet service stops running in that node due to various other errors.

Comment: In the past, we experienced few nodes not ready in the cluster and observed service to service communication issues. so now want to replicate the same behavior to improve/add the monitoring layer.

Comment: I wonder if since Ready/NotReady is based on Disk pressure, Network Availability etc, maybe it's possible to add custom node checks or something, idk https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/monitor-node-health/

Comment: Maybe it's also possible to mess with network configuration to make the node inaccessible, which would cause it to become NotReady i think?

Answer (score 0):

1. ssh to worker node and stop kubelet. ([SSH to EKS Worker Nodes](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/161))
2. taken from [How to simulate nodeNotReady for a node in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56705674/9929015):

---

> Another way is to overload the Node which will cause: System OOM
> encountered and that will result in Node NotReady state. This is just
> one of the ways of how to achieve it: SSH into the Node you want to
> get into NotReady Install
> [Stress](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948854/how-do-i-stress-test-cpu-and-ram-at-the-same-time)
> Run stress: `stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --hdd 10 --vm 4 --vm-bytes 1024M --timeout 5m` (you can adjust the values of course) Wait till Node crash. After you stop the stress the Node should get back to healthy
> state automatically.